# React-Native, dependencys. Login from google

Tags: react-native

I can't run app. I get a message that there are duplicate class / dependencies.

error:

[image: first part]

and next part

[image: second part]

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
 implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
 implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
 implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
 ...
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: My advice is to open your project with `Android Studio`.